# How to inherit and overide object in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, javascript-objects

I have a react `StyleSheet` with objects

```
  const styleSheet = StyleSheet.create({
    picture1: {
      height: 50,
      width: 30,
      alighItems: 'center',
    }
    picture2: {
      height: 50,
      width: 50:,
      alighItems: 'center',
    }
  })
```

My question is :
How do I assign properties of `picture1` to `picture2`, and ovveride width to 50?

So I could write just picture2: {width: 50} without having to rewrite same code?

I tried this way but unfortunately it didn't work.

```
 const styleSheet = StyleSheet.create({
    picture1: {
      height: 50,
      width: 30,
      alighItems: 'center',
    }
    picture2: {
      ...picture1,
      width: 50:,
    }
  })
```

Comment: First create the object and then pass them in

Answer (score 2):

```
  const picture1 = {
    height: 50,
    width: 30,
    alignItems: 'center', // Note: alignItems not alighItems!
  }
  const styleSheet = StyleSheet.create({
    picture1,
    picture2: {
      ...picture1,
      width: 50,
    }
  })
```